# If condition is true, the function in if statement not execute and the application has stopped working

Tags: java, android, arrays

**1)** I was getting the address from the google map by tap on the map and store 
 the value with the code  `place = PlacePicker.getPlace(parentActivity, data);`.

**2)** After I get the address store in `place`, I use the code   `String address[] = place.getAddress().toString().split(",");` to split the address with comma.

**3)** After I have selected use this location, the application stopped working and closed, not even to run the `locationAlertDialog();` method.

I got the error with the `address[address.length-2]` because it no value sometimes depend on user choosing the place where no have complete address, so I can manage with if, else condition for do checking, if the value is null I show the AlertDialog builder which allow user to enter manually.

**Error:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   length=1; index=-1
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1;
>   index=-1

**Below is my code:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode== 1) {
            place = PlacePicker.getPlace(parentActivity, data);
            String address[] = place.getAddress().toString().split("\\,");
            String location ;

            if(address[address.length-2] == null || address[address.length-2].trim().isEmpty() || address[address.length-2].length() < 0 ){
                locationAlertDialog();  **<---The function is not execute and the application stopped working**

            }
            else{
                locationAlertDialog();
                location = place.getName() + "," + address[address.length-2] + "," + address[address.length-1];
                locationET.setText(location);
            }

        }else if (requestCode == Config.PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {
            if (data == null) {
                //no data present
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean `.split(",")` instead of `.split("\\,")`

Comment: Both have try and I get same problem, the problem is the  `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=-1`

Comment: In this case, I would like to check the length before you try to use `address[address.length-2]` ...

Comment: I recommand to use `address.length-2 < 0` instead of `address[address.length-2] == null`

Comment: if your array size is 1 then you are doing `address.length-2` that is why you are getting `index` -1

Comment: if you want to get the item at index `address.length-2`, the `address.length`'s size have to be greater than 2

Comment: Seems like there is no comma in your address, that's why the length of address is 1.

Comment: He is adding data in address only 1 time i guess, as he mentioned he tried splitting with `,`.

Comment: Don't access specific cell in an array without doing some check on the length first.

Comment: @YCF_L it same, I still can check with `address.length-2 < 2` I just messes with wrong concept. Thank you.

Comment: @raul1ro Yeah ! Thank a lot, you save my time, now it work!

Comment: @AxelH Thanks, that's true!

Comment: @TamHuynh I wanted to less than 2, anyway you are right just it not greater than.

Answer (score 0):

`String address[] = place.getAddress().toString().split("\\,");`

This means you are trying to split your address with `\\,` but what if your address does not contain `\\,` or has only one `\\,` match. In those cases your `address[]` will have 0 or 1 element only.

**Afterwards**,

`if(address[address.length-2] == null || address[address.length-2].trim().isEmpty() || address[address.length-2].length() < 0 ){`

in this line you are trying to access `address[address.length-2]`th element, which will not be present.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error means that you are trying access element which is not present in the array. example *you have 5 elements & trying to fetch 6th one.*

Comment: nice explain, I was understanding the concept, I brainstorming messes with the wrong condition, I should use `address.length-2 < 0` instead of `address[address.length-2].length() < 0 `

Comment: Please accept & upvote this answer, if helped. Happy Coding!

Comment: Don't ask for upvotes, but point to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This will give a better explanation on what is the point of the upvotes, but also the opposite.